# how-to resize a partition

Tags: linux, disk

I am trying to resize the `/data` partition from `40G` to `240G`.
Can you please help me understand the setup by answering the below questions?

The setup is as follows:

```
light-07-data:~ # fdisk -l
GPT PMBR size mismatch (209715199 != 629145599) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D482F96A-05F7-47CE-ACCE-29D64D5CC765

Device         Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1026047  1024000  500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048  74426367 73400320   35G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  205518848 209715166  4196319    2G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   74426368  95397887 20971520   10G Linux LVM
/dev/sda5   95397888 179283967 83886080   40G Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

light-07-data:~ # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  300G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   35G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0   10G  0 part /home
└─sda5   8:5    0   40G  0 part /data
sr0     11:0    1    4G  0 rom 


light-07-data:~ # pvdisplay
light-07-data:~ # vgdisplay
light-07-data:~ # lvdisplay
light-07-data:~ #
```

`parted` complains when I try to resize it:

```
light-07-data:~ # parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit GB                                                          
(parted) print                                                            
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 322GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      0.00GB  0.53GB  0.52GB  fat16                 boot, esp
 2      0.53GB  38.1GB  37.6GB  ext4
 4      38.1GB  48.8GB  10.7GB  ext4                  lvm
 5      48.8GB  91.8GB  42.9GB  ext4                  lvm
 3      105GB   107GB   2.15GB  linux-swap(v1)        swap

(parted) resizepart 5                                                     
Warning: Partition /dev/sda5 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes
End?  [91.8GB]? 200GB                                                     
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
(parted) quit
```

Does the above mean that I have to delete the `swap` partition, then resize the `/data` partition like I tried above?
Then, use `resize2fs` to grow the filesystem?

Why `parted` notifies me about  `Warning: Partition /dev/sda5 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?`? What should I do about it?

Why `lvdisplay` does not list `/data` as a LVM volume? So that I can extend it via `lvextend`?

Finally, should I use `swapoff` & `swapon` before using `parted`?

Comment: Welcome, can you post an image of gparted? It will be easier to understand the situation.

Comment: This is five questions in one, to be honest. 1. yes 2. yes 3. unmount the filesystem 4. because your system apparently does not use LVM 5. this depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I agree with Panki except for point 5. Since you want to extend the data partition, you need to remove the swap partition first. So, stop swapping (`swapoff /dev/sda3`), remove partition 3, resize partition 5, add a swap partition again (if you think you need it) and `swapon SWAP_PARTITION`. And if you care for the content of this disk, don't forget to create a backup before you start messing with it.

Comment: thank you @Panki, in order for the system to use LVM the `/` partition has to be based on LVM? the `/data` partition is LVM based, at least this is how it reports. I'll try the steps above and keep you posted.

Comment: thank you @berndbausch. noted ;)